# Trouble logging into Ubuntu Studio on Virtual Box V 5.0.8

Tags: ubuntu-studio

I recently downloaded an iso of Ubuntu Studio to test out, so I created the virtual machine and loaded it up and hit the option to try Ubuntu Studio. As soon as it loaded I was asked for a username and password. I have looked online for the username and password but I can't seem to find one. Has anyone else had this problem? If so what was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The username used to be "ubuntustudio", and the password just nothing (hit enter), for "ubuntustudio live" (wich is the name of the version you get when you choose the option to try ubuntustudio when loading the installation iso)
However, it shouldn't ask you for a username and password, it should just load the system and throw you directly to the desktop for the default user.

You can also try to boot it from a usb stick, the easiest way to make a stick bootable is to install it with "UnetBootin" wich is available for Windows and Linux.  The good thing on this choice is that via UnetBootin you can set (at installation time) some space for saving session configuration and files, this is called "persistence", all stuff gets saved when you log out without any user interaction, into a squash filesystem on the usb stick, wich can also be mounted via Linux for reading, saving, or repairing i.e. with fsck.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem was but it seems to have solved its self and I haven't had any trouble with it since.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes it happened to me too, but I didn't want to answer "just try again".  :)